# Overlay not working when I upgrade to jQuery 1.12.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

Good day,

I am upgrading my web application system jQuery to version 1.12.1. And found that the `overlay` is not working in new jQuery version.

I am using ajax to pop out a dialog with overlay. Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: locurl,
        data: dataPackage,
        success: function(result){
            createServiceModel();
            $("#viewService").dialog({
                height: 645,
                width: 720,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: true,
                bgiframe: true,
                overlay: {
                    opacity: 0.4, 
                    backgroundColor: "black"
                }
            });

                $("#serviceContent").append(result);
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            if(xhr.status==403) alert("You are not allowed to proceed due to changes in your profile. Please re-log in again.");
            else alert("Connection Error. Please try again later. If error persisted, please contact System Administrator.");
        }
    });
```

This is working fine with my old jQuery.

Here is the html code I copy from Chrome debug mode:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-overlay" style="border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1343px; height: 628px; opacity: 0.4; background-color: red; z-index: 1001;"></div>

<div class="ui-dialog ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" 
    style="display:block;position:absolute;width:720px;height:645px;overflow:hidden;z-index:1002;outline:0px;top:5px;left:311.5px;;;">
    <!-- other html code here -->
    </div>
```

I found that the `ui-dialog-overlay` is actually can find from `ui.dialog.js`.

However, when I upgrade to jQuery UI 1.12.1, I found that `ui-dialog-overlay` no longer exists in the jquery-ui.js, but become `ui-dialog-overlays`.

I downloaded the latest jQuery js files from http://jqueryui.com/download/

Is it the `overlay` syntax changes in ajax code?
I tried change the `overlay` by adding 's' on it to

```
overlays: {
            opacity: 0.4, 
            backgroundColor: "black"
        }
```

But still not working.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Remove `async: false`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I tried before actually, not working.

Comment: It may not fix the immediate problem, but you should do it anyway as using `async: false` is very bad practice. If you check the console you'll even see warnings telling you not to use it

Comment: It may also be worth upgrading your jQueryUI version, if you havent already

Comment: hey, same problem here.. can't get it to work for the life of me..did you end up with any solution?

Comment: @mikey, Sorry I forgot to post my answer. I actually found the solution, please refer to my answer. Let me know if you still hitting problem, I will try to help base on my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day,

I found my own solution.

I should not only upgrade jQuery. But I need to upgrade the jQuery UI and also the css file as well.

For this case, I hit this problem is because of my `ui.dialog.css` is still at the old version, and the overlay class name is not match, that's why the overlay function not work.

After I upgrade my ui.dialog.css, my problem solved.

Comment: Thanks. This solved a very similar problem I encountered on upgrade of jquery-ui.  I had neglected to include the upgraded css, which caused a dialog to be blocked.